# having issue understanding blocks variable scope

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

int tnt=1;

-(void)myMethod{

    void(^blk)(void) = ^(void){
        tnt = 3+1;
        NSLog(@"tnt=>%d", tnt);
    };

    blk();
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self myMethod];
}
```

The variable tnt is outside but inside block its working perfectly fine. If i declare the tnt variable inside myMethod it start giving the __block required error.

In both case the tnt variable is outside of the block. Apple docs also says variable outside need __block storage type. Why its working when tnt is declared outside of myMethod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that is related to scope. From the documentation:

> Variables local to the enclosing lexical scope declared with the
>   __block storage modifier are provided by reference and so are mutable. Any changes are reflected in the enclosing lexical scope, including
>   any other blocks defined within the same enclosing lexical scope.
>   These are discussed in more detail in “The __block Storage Type.”

When you put `int tnt=1;` outside the lexical scope, I think you won't have to use the `__block` modifier. And you have an example, [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html). You can also read the following:

> __block variables live in storage that is shared between the lexical scope of the variable and all blocks and block copies declared or
>   created within the variable’s lexical scope. Thus, the storage will
>   survive the destruction of the stack frame if any copies of the blocks
>   declared within the frame survive beyond the end of the frame (for
>   example, by being enqueued somewhere for later execution). Multiple
>   blocks in a given lexical scope can simultaneously use a shared
>   variable.

Since the `int tnt=1;` is declared outside the lexical scope, it will survive the destruction of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables don't need to be captured.